# Testing my Ruby on Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

I have a controller called productscontroller in that method named HomePage.

Code is as follows:

```
   class ProductsController < ApplicationController
      def HomePage
      end
   end
```

In routes.rb file

`root :to => 'products#HomePage'`

So when i click `localhost:3000` it renders homepage.

For this HomePage.html.erb file, I am calling javascript file, in this javascript file am sending another ajax request to render centre content.
`Path: 'homepage01/1'` for this request i have action in the controller like

```
def homepage01
 "query executed and stored in instance variable"
end
```

so My question is how to test whether this page is rendered successfully or any error etc in testing framewoks?

Answer (score 0):

It's simple with rspec:
create test in spec/controllers/products_controller_spec.rb with following code:

```
describe ProductsController do
  describe '#homepage01' do
    before { get :homepage01 }

    it { should respond_with(:success) }
    it { should render_template(:template_name) }
end
```

Comment: No route matches {:controller=>"products", :action=>"homepage01"} i have included                                                    group :test, :development do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'cucumber-rails'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem "factory_girl_rails", "~> 4.0"
end in gem file. Should i missing something?

Comment: look in your routes by calling 'rake routes' - this will show all available paths in your app - controllers and actions.
I think you got this error cause in your routes.rb this path is not defined.
Try to add smth like this

    resources :products, :path => '', :only => [:HomePage, :homepage01]
    get 'products/homepage01'
    get 'products/HomePage'

But this name is very bad, you should use REST and CRUD actions for simplicity

Comment: i fixed routing error by using     visit root_path but now getting        Failure/Error: it { should respond_with(:success) }
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `respond_with' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_1:0xb94c9a0>

Comment: No, you should use 'get' - visit is for integration tests, not for controllers